# Using iTerm2 how can I get rid of the XXXXXXXX if the terminal has too many lines in them?

Tags: iterm

My terminal has 475 lines in them and I can't scroll back to the first lines because it displays: `XXXXXX`

like this:

```
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  ChronoModel metadata for tags (3.2ms)  SELECT obj_description('tags'::regclass)
  ChronoModel metadata for departments (0.8ms)  SELECT obj_description('departments'::regclass)
...
...
<475 lines are here>
...
...
```

How can I unset the boundary?

In my settings I have `Unlimited scrollback`... but I still see this so this must be another setting...

Comment: I use iTerm2 regularly, never seen X's like that. My outputs often have many thousands of lines, and I can scroll back to the first line no prob. Do you have more than one Profile? A way to find out if it's an obscure setting in a particular profile would be to start fresh with a new Profile with default settings. Could the X's actually be the output of whatever generates the 475 lines?  I poked and prodded iTerm2 's settings - which are manifold, so maybe I'm missing the operative thing, too - but can't find any way to get those X's. Does the same thing happen in Apple's Terminal.app?

Comment: That doesn't happen in Apple's built-in terminal app. Just in `iTerm2`

Comment: A created a new window with the default profile and it works now, so I don't know what was the issue... Thank You anyway for the tip.